# Loopbackjs custom methods not showing in relations

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

In Strong loop i have a User model, and a Messages model. The Messages model has a custom method added in the message.js file. Lets say it's called

```
Message.sendMessage
```

This works fine at the messages end point. I've then added the messages model to the User model as a one to many - this works fine and i can now see all the messages models that are predefined, but not my methods added via actually code. So the basic CRUD methods work, but not custom methods. Any idea how to make these show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Message.sendMessage` is a static method and cannot be invoked from a model instance.

If you want to invoke it from the instances of the `Message` class, you need to define it as `Message.prototype.sendMessage`

Comment: Sorry do you mean the User class? I can invoke the custom method when calling sendMessage method regardless of if it's prototype or not from the Message method - just not from the User method, but i still get all of Messages other methods showing up in User due to the relationship.